# Rotate VPN on Router Automatically

Tags: networking, router, vpn, proxy, dd-wrt

I am running DD-WRT on my router with a VPN configured. I would like to have the VPN rotated through a database of VPN server addresses.

Ideally a script would SSH into the router and change the VPN settings and there would be no down time (or perhaps a few seconds). But from what I've read the router must be rebooted after the VPN settings are updated, which would take awhile.

Are there any solutions to have a VPN setting on a router changed on the fly with a script with very little down time?

I am open to using any open source router firmware, it does not have to be DD-WRT.

Thank you.

Comment: On [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/), a `/etc/init.d/network restart` command should restart most VPN set-ups. I don't know if this works on DD-WRT.

Comment: Having to reboot a router to change a VPN on dd-wrt is incorrect.  You should specify the VPN protocol(s) in your post and also confirm if, other then IP address of server the credentials remain the same. Also, should thus rotation be automatic or triggered from another device?

Comment: dd-wrt is a variant of unix - albeit one that uses Busybox.  I do wonder if part of your difficulty is that you are using OpenVPN from the web Interface.   I have a moderately complex OpenVPN setup on my router - but I do it from the command line - it might be this difference which is why you believe you need to reboot the router when you make a change. You might want to specify the version of dd-wrt you are using and if you have jffs enabled.

Comment: @bitinerant I dont think /etc/init.d/network restart works on dd-wrt  - I created /jjffs/etc/config - You can automatically run scripts based on triggers like startup, interface going up or down etc - see https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Execution

Comment: is someone able to post an example of dd-wrt vpn setting being updated on the fly? i'm open to pretty much any code language